# SQLServer Delete from table with list coming from another table

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-delete, inner-query

I have a DELETE requiring a where with an AND in the WHERE clause to pick the rows. One the of values in the WHERE is actually a bunch of ids. I could accomplish with programming to get the list of user ids and then looping using the list.

```
This query returns a list of GroupUserIds
SELECT Id FROM GroupUser WHERE GroupUserId = @GroupUserId
```

I this wish to delete from VariableTransaction for each GroupUserId

```
Foreach @GroupUserId in GroupUserIds
DELETE FROM VariableTransaction WHERE VariableId = @VariableId AND GroupUserId = @GroupUserId
```

There should be a way to combine these into a single SQL statement but looking at all the examples I cannot figure out a solution, the where with the AND complicates it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an IN clause with a subquery:

```
DELETE FROM VariableTransaction WHERE VariableId = @VariableId
AND GroupUserId IN (SELECT Id FROM GroupUser WHERE GroupUserId = @GroupUserId)
```